# Why am I not able to access the internet via this NAT instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have an EC2 instance at `10.0.3.22` within a private subnet.

I have another EC2 instance in a public subnet, which I'm trying to use as a NAT instance (to save costs over a AWS-provided NAT gateway). For the most part, I have followed [this guide](https://www.kabisa.nl/tech/cost-saving-with-nat-instances/).

The NAT instance has the following user data, using the mime multi-part format documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-mime-multi).

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#! /bin/bash
yum install iptables-services -y
systemctl enable iptables
systemctl start iptables

sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
--//--
```

I am able to SSH into the NAT instance, and confirm that I can access the internet from there (using `ping ietf.org`). From that SSH session, I can SSH into the instance in the private subnet at `10.0.3.22`, but from here I cannot access the internet:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-3-22 ~]$ ping ietf.org
PING ietf.org (50.223.129.194) 56(84) bytes of data.
From ip-10-0-4-248.eu-west-1.compute.internal (10.0.4.248) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Prohibited
```

Why might this not be working?

The route table for the private subnet (where eni-0a3... is the network interface of the NAT EC2 instance):

[image: route table for private subnet]

And the route table for the public subnet containing the NAT EC2 instance:

[image: route table for public subnet]

I have disabled the Source/Destination check on the NAT EC2 instance.

Security group for the instance in the private subnet:

[image]

Security group for the NAT instance:

[image]

Comment: Are the security groups configured properly?

Comment: @Paolo possibly not...I have added them to the question

Comment: The security group of the private instance should have an outgoing rule with destination the security group of the nat instance, likewise the security group of the nat instance should have an inbound rule whitelisting traffic from the security group of the private instance. I'd highly recommend using Reachability Analyser in these cases

Comment: Is that required in addition to the rules I already have? I'll give it a go but I don't really understand why it would be necessary - SSH and ping are already working between the two instances, after all.

Comment: SSH uses port 22 and ping uses ICMP. Internet traffic will use http or https, hence you need TCP port 80 and TCP port 443

Comment: I have added these extra rules to the security groups (see updated screenshots) but it doesn't seem to have solved the issue.

Comment: I reckon the rules you already had have a higher priority. Try using the Reachability Analyzer

Comment: The Reachability Analyzer is showing that the instances are reachable from one another for TCP. My original issue though is that I can't ping a server on the internet from my private instance. I'm not sure how to use the Reachability Analyzer to debug that.

Comment: Check this page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#NATSG , might be useful

Comment: One thing that is not clear to me from those docs is this - does the EC2 instance need to have two network interfaces attached in order to operate as a NAT router?

Comment: You haven't described the subnet network ACLs. Are they the [defaults](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#default-network-acl)?

Comment: Yes, they are the defaults

Answer (score 2):

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Created a VPC with one Public and one Private subnet, plus Internet Gateway (no NAT Gateway):

[image: VPC Architecture]

- Created a Security Group allowing All Traffic both Inbound and Outbound to/from `0.0.0.0/0` (This is bad for security, but good for temporary testing)
- Launched an instance (`public-ec2`) in the Public subnet using the above security group and using the **User Data** from your Question
- Launched an instance (`private-ec2`) in the Private subnet using the above security group

Then, to check how things went:

- Logged into `public-ec2` and looked in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` to verify that the User Data ran (yes, I saw stuff referencing the installation of `iptables`)
- From `public-ec2`, used SSH to connect to `private-ec2` -- worked fine
- Ran `curl google.com` which, as expected, failed due to no Internet connection from the private instance

Next, update the network:

- **Deactivated Source/Destination Check** on `public-ec2`
- Modified the **private route table** to send `0.0.0.0/0` traffic to `public-ec2`

A final test:

- From the private instance, I again tried to `curl` a public website. **It did not work.**

I even went back into `public-ec2` and manually ran the commands from your script, but that didn't fix anything.

Therefore, **I think the problem lies in the "NAT Script"**, which is not correctly making the instance pass-through the traffic.

Comment: Ah! I wonder if the problem is that these scripts used to work with older AMIs, but are not compatible (in some way) with the 'modern' AMIs we are using?

Comment: Yes, possibly. I think one potential issue is that the network interface isn't actually named `eth0` but instead is `ens5`